# Minecraft: View who is online in a server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a website and would like to display a list of players online in my server. Most likely a php or javascript function would be ideal. Is this information public or do I need server mods to do this?

https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/status/
Has a version where if an IP:port is specified, the list of players is returned. I would like a version like this on my site, except for just my server.

Does anyone know of anything like this?

Comment: Do you mean like a list that you see when you click "Tab" in game? It's certainly possible to do, and I have seen it been done before on servers.

Comment: @Chantola He's trying to integrate Dinnerbone's tool onto his Website, like a HTML; web version of the player list. | Also, I'm sure there's a plugin that does this. (Just don't know what it's called)

Comment: I'm not trying to use Dinnerbone's tool but just implement something similar to it where it would just show who is online in the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this your server needs to have **RCON** enabled.
Basically that allows services to access data from your server. (Read more about RCON [here](http://wiki.vg/Rcon))

An example implementation in PHP that you could use on your website would be this:
https://bitbucket.org/jyc/rcon/overview

Or you could use the same code Dinnerbone used:
https://github.com/Dinnerbone/mcstatus

Comment: Would the fact that dinnerbone's server stats tool works on my server mean that RCON is enabled?